# Three.js How to make the camera rotate around the center of an object

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I had to create an interior camera of my object and for that to work I had to offset my object from the center. Now the problem is that I want the camera to rotate from the center of the object and not around the center of my scene. Here are some images [one](https://ibb.co/CwV0GqV) [two](https://ibb.co/GtxYG75) [three](https://ibb.co/SctsL7F) that will explain the problem. As you can see, looking at the car from the back it appears closer than looking from the front.

```
// Camera
const fov = 75;
const near = 0.1;
const far = 1000;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, near, far);
camera.position.set(0, 1, 4);

// Camera Controls
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 3;
controls.maxDistance = 5;
controls.minDistance = 3;
controls.autoRotate = true;
controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.2;
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.addEventListener( "change", event => {
console.log( controls.object.position );
});
controls.update()
```

Comment: `OrbitControls` has [`.target`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.target) property.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you. It works!

Comment: @Archon can you show me how to this in a just a loop without controlling the camera? I can't understand it will and also the `.target` you guys talking about. I'm trying it but it doesn't make it work out.. Just a simple demo will do thanks bro :> .

Comment: @MythVince I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. You can check the official documentation [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls) on ".target", also [Vector3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3). What I did was that I moved my object from the central position which is (0,0,0) and I had to change the camera position to reflect that.